# Setting delay on ajax form submisson

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to delay the form submission by 2 seconds. I see lot of solutions but they are not working for me. I tried setting delay with setTimeout but not working 100%. Below is my script and form tag: where can i add the logic to setTimeout?

```
$("#leadForm${leadForm.index}").ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit : function(arr) {
    $("#loadingSpan").show();
    $('#submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  },
  success: function() {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'event' : 'formSubmissionSuccess',
      'formId' : 'leadForm${leadForm.productCode}'
    });
  },
  target : "#leadFormDiv${leadForm.index}"
});
```

```html
<form action="/portal/individual/leads/form/product/${leadForm.productCode}/submit.do" id="leadForm${leadForm.index}" method="POST" commandName="leadForm" role="form" class="form-default form-dui" data-dui-form="">
```

Comment: You can check jQuery `.delay()` option. It might help you. https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: _“where can i add the logic to setTimeout?”_ – you seem to be using some kind of plugin here (`ajaxForm`), which sets up all the necessary event handlers itself. So unless that plugin explicitly provides a means to achieve what you want (unlikely), it is probably going to be rather tricky to implement this on top of it. If you wrote your own code that sets its own form submission handler, this would be much easier.

Comment: As you're using `ajaxForm()` you've lost control of the relation between the form submission and the AJAX request being sent. This means you cannot delay the request with your current logic. You would need to hook up the AJAX request manually using `$.ajax`. Then you can wrap that call in a `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

From the API on the website you could do this:

```
$("#leadForm${leadForm.index}").submit(function() { 
    $("#loadingSpan").show();
    $('#submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#leadForm${leadForm.index}").ajaxSubmit({
            success: function() {
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                window.dataLayer.push({
                   'event' : 'formSubmissionSuccess',
                   'formId' : 'leadForm${leadForm.productCode}'
                });
            },
            target : "#leadFormDiv${leadForm.index}"
        });
    }, 2000);
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but this dint show the behavior I was expecting and timeout also dint work.

Comment: In this case you should change the type of the submit button. If you use a _type="button"_ instead of _type="submit"_ you can handle the submission manually by using _$("form").submit();_
For a more accurate answer I need to see the form content

Answer (score 0):

From this [source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-form#beforesubmit):

**beforeSubmit**: beforeSubmit
Callback function invoked prior to form submission. Returning false from the callback will prevent the form from being submitted.

I believe if you could set a 2 seconds timeout here It will wait for 2 seconds then calls the submit functions.

Can you try this one and check if it is working:

```
beforeSubmit : function(arr) {
           setTimeout(function(){ $("#loadingSpan").show();
           $('#submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled"); return true;}, 2000);
           }
```

Comment: This won't work. Simply because the _beforeSubmit_ and the _submit_ are called sequencially. Even if you set a Timeout in _beforeSubmit_ the function will be considered ended as soo as the Timeout is set. Also in this way you're showing the spinner and disabling the button 2 seconds after the action, which is not a suitable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the response.
Will try other solutions suggested here, but for now I tried below and is working.

I just called below function on button click.

```
  function sendFormWithDelay() {

    $('.spinner-action').show();
    $('#submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#submitBtn1').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#backbutton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var id = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#leadForm${leadForm.index}").submit();

    },2000);//delaying the submit for 2 seconds so that ninja lead response is returned.

    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you had specified in your question that using the ajaxForm plugin wasn't necessary, you would have got this answer from anyone..

Comment: $("#leadForm${leadForm.index}").submit(); in above function actually calls the ajaxForm plugin, the code that initially posted  above.

Comment: No it doesn't. The _.submit()_ is simple jQuery...There must be an event listener set with ajaxForm that catches the submit(). Anyway glad you solved. Cheers.